# How to Set image size in grid view

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I have a grid view with 3 columns wrapped in a relative layout.
At the moment the view on a large device (7 inch tablet) appears small so I want to increase the size of the images according to the screen size.

My getView() in baseApdter for the Gridview:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        AppInfo entry = mListAppInfo.get(position);

        //create a new ImageView and TextView for each item refernced by teh adpter


        if(convertView == null) {

            //if its not recycled, intilise some attributs

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
        }

        //want to change the soze of the image according to screensize then place in the gridview with this apdter


        ImageView ivIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);

        //ivIcon.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                //(int)mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.widthImageGridview),
                //(int)mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.heihgtImageGridview)));
        ivIcon.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        ivIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        ivIcon.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        ivIcon.setImageBitmap(entry.getIcon());

        TextView tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvName.setText(entry.getName());
        tvName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);       
        return convertView;
    }
```

And my XML with grid view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".Main" >

        <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gvMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="200dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="40dip"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_facebook"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fb_button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Trying to use the imageView.setLayoutparams(...) throws

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to
>   android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception was caused by your code here:

```
ivIcon.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

change to:

```
ivIcon.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(85, 85));
```

because you were using LinearLayout in layout_appinfo.xml.
When you set layout param for any object, it depends on parent layout type.

Comment: http://simply-tutorial.com/blog/2014/06/11/how-to-solve-error-when-casting-layoutparams-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

You may try like codes.

```
ivIcon.setColumnWidth(number);
        ivIcon.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used a GridView, I didn't specify a `columnWidth`. The columns automatically stretched to fill the screen.

Comment: Thanks, tired both suggestions but still no change is image size within the grid view...